# Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces after reboot

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I have a python script that sniffs using scapy library.
I want my raspberry to reboot every X minutes, put my wifi dongle network card in monitor mode and restart the sniffing script. In the meantime I need internet connection via ethernet.

My first attempt was to set a crontab like this

```
@reboot sudo shutdown -r +X
@reboot sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
@reboot sudo airmon-ng start wlan1 
@reboot sudo python myScript.py
```

and it worked.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.87  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::4033:ce91:f9f7:c6c6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:26:91:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 164  bytes 17133 (16.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 196  bytes 33373 (32.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:73:c4:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1mon: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        unspec 00-C0-CA-97-F0-1D-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 6  bytes 832 (832.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But then raspberry started to give different names to wireless cards (wlan1 to in-built wireless card and wlan0 to the external usb dongle). My python script always sniffs with wlan1mon so I don't want this change.
So I enabled predictable interfaces from `raspi-config` and the usb dongle started to be named `wlx????????????` where `????????????` is the mac address.
It seems all ok but when I change my crontab to

```
@reboot sudo shutdown -r +X
@reboot sudo ifconfig wlx???????????? up
@reboot sudo airmon-ng start wlx???????????? 
@reboot sudo python myScript.py
```

if I type the command `iwconfig` wlx???????????? is correctly set to wlan1mon beacuse of the too long name the interface would have but I don't have anymore internet connection via ethernet and ifconfig give me this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
enxb827eb269126: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::4033:ce91:f9f7:c6c6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:26:91:26  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 164  bytes 17133 (16.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 196  bytes 33373 (32.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

wlan0 and wlan1mon are not here anymore and from ethernet interface field inet is missing.
iwconfig instead give me this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ iwconfig
enxb827eb269126 no wireless extensions 

wlan0    IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any
         Mode:Managed Access Point:Not-Associated
         Retry short limit:27 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
         Power Management:on

wlan1mon IEEE 802.11 Mode:Monitor Tx-Power=20dBm
         Retry short long limit:2 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
         Power Management:off

lo       no wireless extensions
```